# Android studio, i want to make app, if i click button in activity 1 then open card view in activity 2 and posible to swipe with viewpager

Tags: android

I have many buttons on activity 1
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5cCp.png) if I click the button on activity 1 then display the cardview on activity 2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsvDD.png) and can to swipe right or left with viewpager (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaHOS.png)

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, please create a [mcve]

Comment: I'm so sorry, I don't know, this is my first question in stack overlow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using an ArrayList to populate the Activity 1?
If Yes on click of one of your button you should pass your arrayList in activity 2 with the position (position of the button clicked). After you do that your viewpager shou have the same number of pages as the arraylist.size().
After than you can scroll left or right as you asked for